# JQuery POST function

Tags: jquery

I am using this JQuery function to post forms:

```
function SubmitForm(form, postaction) {
    $(form).submit(function(event){
        $('#LoadingDiv').show();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(postaction, data)
        .success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
            $('.tabcontent').html(result);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        })
        .error(function(){
            $('.tabcontent').html('Error Loading Page');
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

            console.log('Error loading page');
        })
        return false;
    });
}
```

I have the buttons on the forms like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="SubmitForm('#SearchHistoricInvoices', '/billing/viewhistoricinvoices.php');" value="Search" />
```

and the form tag:

```
<form method="post" id="SearchHistoricInvoices">
```

but when submitting the form using the above button, it just seems to refresh the whole page and not actually submit the form

i have checked the console, and there are no errors

Comment: You are binding submit handler inside onclick handler. I guess, your submit handler isn't fired and so the FORM is submited

Comment: Remove the `type="submit"` from the `<input>`. Doing this enables the default form submit behavior that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the function directly instead of calling inside another function.

```
$('#SearchHistoricInvoices').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            $('#LoadingDiv').show();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).prop('action'), data)
            .success(function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
                $('.tabcontent').html(result);
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            })
            .error(function(){
                $('.tabcontent').html('Error Loading Page');
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

                console.log('Error loading page');
            })
            return false;
        });
```

Try using jQuery `event.preventDefault()` in first line as mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Your code should be like this

```
    function SubmitForm(form, postaction) {
        $(form).submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            $('#LoadingDiv').show();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post(postaction, data)
            .success(function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
                $('.tabcontent').html(result);
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            })
            .error(function(){
                $('.tabcontent').html('Error Loading Page');
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

                console.log('Error loading page');
            })
            return false;
        });
    }
```

This will stop the default `submit event` and will use jQuery post to send request.

Comment: i have just tried this, and the #LoadingDiv shows and does not hide so i dont think its submitted properly still

Comment: @Charles This means your server is not sending `200 OK` response header. There is something wrong with the request then. Can you paste the error log from error console ?

Comment: there are a few errors that say Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Is jQuery framework library included ?? also you have to paste the complete html and js error

Comment: what version of JQuery would i need? I will check that i have the right version?

Comment: try using the latest version: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: brilliant - thank you! is there any way to keep these posted values? for example, i have page numbers with next/prev buttons and i want to keep he search results when changing pages. <input type="button" onClick="OpenPage(\'/wp_pages/my_integra/pages/'.basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]).'?pagenum='.$back.'\');" value="Previous" />

Comment: would it be better to use GET rather than POST so the values can stay in the GET variables

Comment: @Charles it for you to decide. If it's not critical data you can use `GET`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you only attach the form `submit` handler *after* the form has been submit. Change your logic to use jQuery event hooks and it becomes much simpler and neater. Try this:

```
<form method="post" id="SearchHistoricInvoices" action="/billing/viewhistoricinvoices.php">
    <!-- other inputs -->
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

```js
$('#SearchHistoricInvoices').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $.post($(this).prop('action'), $(this).serialize()).success(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
        $('.tabcontent').html(result);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }).error(function(){
        $('.tabcontent').html('Error Loading Page');
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        console.log('Error loading page');
    })
});
```